# How to deal with rotation of an element in theory of elasticity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses, elastic-modulus

As you know in linear theory of elasticity equations for strains are given as (according to picture):
[image]

But what will be if an element will just rotate (strain equation is on the picture):
[image: rotation of an element]

Intuitively i think there should be no strains. The main question is how to deal with it?

Comment: On mobile so can't give full answer, but look up Mohr's circle. You'll have individual strains in both x and y, but you will find one axis x' and y' where you can define no strain.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for [torsion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(mechanics)).

Comment: In the first picture, the equations for the strain use engineering strain which is only valid for small rotations. So in the second picture, $\cos \varphi$ is small (approximately $\cos\varphi = 1 - \frac 1 2 \varphi^2$) and the second-order term $\varphi^2$ is ignored. So $\epsilon_x = 0$. If you want to model large rotations, use Green strain, not engineering strain, and you will get $\epsilon_x = 0$ exactly, for any value of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, your deformation map would be something like

$$
\varphi(x) = 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
xcos(\varphi) - ysin(\varphi) \\
xsin(\varphi) + ycos(\varphi) \\
z \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Deformation gradient
$$
F = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
cos(\varphi) & -sin(\varphi) & 0 \\
sin(\varphi) & cos(\varphi) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Green deformation tensor
$$
G = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
\therefore
E = \frac{1}{2} [G - I] = 0
$$
Which is what we would expect, but in order to calculate this we needed to use higher order terms. Since:
$$
G = FF^T = (\nabla u + I)(\nabla u + I)^T = \nabla u + \nabla u^T + \nabla u \nabla u ^T + I
$$
If each component of:
$$
\nabla u < 1
$$
then each component of:
$$
\nabla u \nabla u ^T \ll 1
$$
We expect our $\varphi$ to be very small, so we can ignore our higher order terms. Let's linearize the deformation gradient:
$$
cos(\varphi) \approx 1, sin(\varphi) \approx \varphi \\
F = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\varphi & 0 \\
\varphi & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right] \\
G = 
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 + \varphi ^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 + \varphi ^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right] \\
\therefore
E = \frac{1}{2}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\varphi ^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \varphi ^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right] \approx 0
$$
This makes since, because if $\varphi$ is small, $\varphi^2$ is much smaller and we can accept the error assuming geometrically linear behavior. We just need to watch out for non-small rotations that will cause our linearization to have a larger error.

---

Resource:

Fundamentals of Structural Mechanics 2nd, Keith D. Hjelmstad

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this lies in the defining equation for the strains that you have supplied. The full displacement gradient $u_{i,j}$ (where the $\bullet_{,j}$ represents the $j^{\rm th}$ derivative) can be linearly decomposed into a symmetric and an anti-symmetric component: $u_{i,j} = \epsilon_{i,j} + \omega_{i,j}$, in the usual way as for all rank-2 tensors.

The symmetric part, $\epsilon_{i,j} = \frac{u_{i,j}+u_{j,i}}{2}$ represents the strain, the only thing that counts for elastic energy, whereas the anti-symmetric part $\omega_{i,j} = \frac{u_{i,j}-u_{j,i}}{2}$ represents rigid body rotation. And as you remarked, this costs no energy to the system. Hence, for elasticity, we only ever talk about $\epsilon_{i,j}$.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering Stack Exchange.  This was a great contribution.